# Maximum economic growth rate in developed countries in the 21st century

Tags: science-based, society, economy, technological-development, manufacturing

Given a hypothetical 500M-1Bn population at the social, economic, political, financial, industrial, military, etc. capacities available in the most developed countries currently (2023, e.g. Nordic countries, continental Europe, U.S., etc.), barring all other considerations, **what is the maximum rate at which economic growth could occur**? Or, in other words, given maximum optimization of a utilitarian society (for example, one at the scale and level of modern-day Europe), how fast would economic growth occur? What is the most plausible way in which this could be achieved?

I am posing this question after looking at double-digit economic growth in China over these past decades. That said, much of China's economic growth was "catching up" to scientific, technological, and industrial capacity of developed nations. **How would one optimize for future growth?** - this is assuming that there is no other "model" or country to copy/replicate technologies etc from.

For example - consider (suspend disbelief, I know this is almost impossible) but a rogue European Union restructuring itself for the very last ounce of economic growth. How would they do this and how effective would it be?

Comment: It very obviously depends on the base from which development starts. If development starts from a very low base, such as the dirt-poor People's Republic as left by the most beloved Chairman Mao, then a high rate of annual growth can be sustained for quite some time. If development starts from a very high base, such as the rich and well-balanced Germany of the early 21st century, then sustaining even a modest growth rate over a reasonably long span of time becomes quite remarkable. The main problem is that if your society is rich and balanced you just don't have any underutilized workforce.

Comment: @AlexP the phrasing of the question may have been unclear, but I'm posing this question to indicate a base of the most developed countries today. Effectively, I'm looking to see in what ways a utilitarian society could, assuming it was implemented tomorrow, maximize economic growth and the specific maximum that would be. I don't know if there are any economic principles which is why I am posing this question.

Comment: In this case you really need to define what it is that you mean by growth. For example, from 1975 to 2020 (45 years), the [real median personal income in the USA](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/MEPAINUSA672N) grew from 26,006 USD/year to 37,529 USD/year (both being expressed in 2021 dollars), an average growth rate of 0.8% per year.

Comment: Chinese GDP under Mao went from 30.55 in 1952 (the first year of data) to 153.94 in 1976 (the last year of Mao), so averaged 7% a year: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_GDP_of_China . Life expectancy went from 45 to 65 under Mao.

Comment: This isn't a worldbuilding question. Try: economics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are we factoring superhuman level artificial intelligence and self-replicating machines into this question?

Answer (score 1):

**Near infinite (almost).**

Once upon a time, most economic activity was based on the [primary sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_sector_of_the_economy), food and raw materials. As a rule of thumb, in classical times and the middle age nine out of ten people worked in agricultulture. Then the [secondary sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_sector_of_the_economy) of manufacturing activities started to overtake it during the industrial revolution. Today, the number of agricultural workers in developed nations is down to the single digits (not counting the industry which makes farm machinery ...). And with increasing specialization, the [tertiary sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertiary_sector_of_the_economy) of services started to grow (people who build the farm machines no longer cook their meals, they pay couriers to bring them take-out dinner ...).

On top of that, an increasing fraction of what is traditionally the secondary sector is becoming bits and bytes. A tractor is not just steel, rubber, and microchips, it is also the latest software release. The effect would be to mostly un-couple economic growth from raw materials, which were a hard limit in the 19th and early 20th century.

One could conceive of a situation where the value of the software in manufactured goods grows dramatically, and where many new services are invented based on software and data. People might use less raw materials, and waste less food, through better services. Instead of buying a car, which stands idle most of the day, one rents a self-driving cab just for the trip. Better monitoring and realtime demand prediction models reduce food waste during transport and in the shops. And so on.

Comment: This is exactly why I said that the OP must first define what they mean by "growth". What you describe is purely growth in abstract numbers, disconnected from any physical reality. Maybe the OP wants this, maybe they want actual growth.

Comment: @AlexP, as an employee in the software sector, I hope that my work is *actual*. Especially where it actually economizes on what used to be done with physical resources alone.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [list of fastest-growing economies 2013-2021](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_real_GDP_growth_rate#List_(2013%E2%80%932021)), and sort the table by the right-hand column: average growth rate over those eight years. The biggest growth is in Libya, second was Guyana, etc.

GDP grows fast in undeveloped countries. When that low-hanging fruit has been picked, it slows down (as is happening in China recently.)

Ireland may seem to be the fastest-growing "developed" economy, but this is misleading because of [Leprechaun economics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leprechaun_economics); in other words because Ireland is a tax haven, the GDP measurement is inflated by foreign money passing through the country. Ireland's GDP growth is not reflective of the growth of its economy.

We've got to move down the table to find developed countries like Israel and Lithuania with growth rates of about 3.7% per year from 2013-2021.

So 3.7% is the empirical answer. But of course you can get away with fictional rates of growth that are much higher depending on the specifics of your worldbuilding, e.g. a country that invents fusion/free energy, or a country that grabs a lucrative colony, or any of a million other possibilities.